# Unit test to test Linux specific code

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test in Java for a method that checks:

```
 if SystemUtils.IS_OS_UNIX
```

Which then flows through the rest of the code. Is it possible to somehow wrap my test so it can pass this check or would the method need to be modified?

EDIT: [SystemUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html) from the Apache Commons library is used

Comment: You want to trick your own test into giving incorrect results?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go that far. I am just trying to find out how the test will react with a different OS but I was looking at options outside of setting up a virtual machine with Unix/Mac.

Answer (score 2):

It should not be your task to write unit tests for external libraries. You should be able to assume that they work. However you might want to mock that call to test different scenarios/Operating System flows.

I recommend [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) to mock static values/methods. There's a very useful [MockStatic method](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for but thanks anyway. I will probably use this for my other tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection. Instead of having your class call out to `SystemUtils.IS_OS_UNIX`, pass a `boolean isOsUnix` into its constructor (or better yet, an `enum osType`). Then the unit test can pass any value it likes.

Comment: I was trying to see if there was an option to this without editing the code. But it doesn't seem like it will work. Thanks.